# How to correct error, Indirect access to variables, properties and methods will be evaluated strictly in left-to-right order since PHP 7.0

Tags: php

I need some help correcting the WP error after my server was upgraged to php 7.0

Indirect access to variables, properties and methods will be evaluated strictly in left-to-right order since PHP 7.0. Use curly braces to remove ambiguity

Here are the 2 lines in question causing the issue

```
    if( is_array( $default) && isset( $default[0] ) && $default[0] == 'execute' ){                          
        $default = $default[1]->$default[2]();                      
    }                           




    else if( isset( $this->ops[$id]['default'] ) ){                         
        $val = $this->ops[$id]['default'];                      
        if( is_array( $val ) && isset( $val[0] ) && $val[0] == 'execute' ){                     
            $val = $val[1]->$val[2]();                  
    }
```

Where would i put the { brackets

references these 2 specific lines

```
$default = $default[1]->$default[2]();
```

and

```
$val = $val[1]->$val[2]();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is interpreted:

```
$val = $val[1]->$val[2]();
```

PHP 5:

```
$val = {$val[1]}->{$val[2]}();
```

PHP 7:

```
$val = ($val[1]->$val)[2]();
```

So to remove the ambiguity use the PHP 5 example with the curly braces:

```
$val = {$val[1]}->{$val[2]}();
```

Comment: Note that in PHP 7.2 and up, you should use `$val[1]->{$val[2]}();` to avoid _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "}"_.  See https://3v4l.org/BFOLc for example.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is working in PHP 5, you should be fine with using:

```
 $default = $default[1]->{$default[2]}();
```

and:

```
 $val = $val[1]->{$val[2]}();
```

in the obvious lines. This should avoid the 'Does not have property "Array"' errors.